# how to user position: sticky in css

Tags: html, css, sticky-session

I have a div in my website and have another div inside it,
I gave the inner div position sticky and top:0 but it doesn't work!
This is my code example:

Above : container is a normal div and inner div has a sticky position and top: 0
But it doesn't work.
Any suggestions to solve this!

```css
.sticky-div{
      background: #fed700;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item1</li>
      </nav>
      <div class="sticky-div">
        Sticky
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
```

Comment: Please share your source code with html and css

Comment: @GeorgeMa
Here it is, but note that i want the inner div sticky not the parent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Position: sticky behavior on a child element whilst the parent is not sticky?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342843/position-sticky-behavior-on-a-child-element-whilst-the-parent-is-not-sticky)

Comment: The element will be sticky while scrolling inside its container. Right now your sticky element won't 'stick' because its container is not scrolling, its probably the body that's scrolling.

Comment: @Rojo
No, I have the same problem but there is no solution for it

Comment: @Sjors
Ok, but what is the solution to do this

Comment: Exactly. And there won't be a solution using sticky. You need to use JS to get the scroll amount and apply different positions like fixed and absolute

Comment: @Rojo
Speak politely and just answer if you know the answer and don't speak that way

Comment: I think this has the best answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53131200/why-sticky-position-does-not-work-in-child-div

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the surrounding container div or make that div sticky.

Comment: Ok friend but in my case the sticky div positioned in the middle of the page not at the top

Answer (score 0):

I believe the sticky positioning will only work if the container that it lays within has stick positions on it.

If you'd like for it to work how it should do this:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sticky-div,
.stickyContainer {
  background: #fed700;
}

.stickyContainer {
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky-div">
  Sticky
</div>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>

<div class="stickyContainer">
  Sticky
</div>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
```

Comment: Ok friend but in my case the sticky div positioned in the middle of the page not at the top

Answer (score 0):

It is positioned according to the user's scrolling position. But all the content must be in the same container, you can either put the texts inside the container or move the sticky element out the container

```css
.sticky-div{
  background: #fed700;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sticky-div">
    Sticky
  </div>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```